# Glass Mapper - Set Buttons and Frame Title for expirence editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, glass-mapper

I would like setup a title for frame and my custom buttons with BeginEditFrame, 
but I can't set it up in last method,

```
public GlassEditFrame BeginEditFrame();
public GlassEditFrame BeginEditFrame(string dataSource);
public GlassEditFrame BeginEditFrame(string buttons, string dataSource);
public GlassEditFrame BeginEditFrame<T>(T model, string title = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] fields) where T : class;
```

Is it any other way to set edit frame title ?

Comment: Why cant you use the last Glass method? Whats the issue you are seeing?

Comment: No Possible to set up buttons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this same situation and ended up creating a derived EditFrame and custom Extension to support titles.

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An extra extensions because the default ones are bugged or do not expose title
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TModel"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="htmlHelper"></param>
    /// <param name="model"></param>
    /// <param name="buttons"></param>
    /// <param name="title"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static GlassEditFrame BeginEditFrame<TModel>(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, TModel model, string buttons, string title = "") where TModel : BaseCommon
    {
        var output = new HtmlTextWriter(htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer);
        var editFrame = new EditFrame()
        {
            DataSource = model.Id.ToString(),
            Buttons = buttons,
            Title = title
        };
        editFrame.RenderFirstPart(output);
        return new CustomGlassEditFrame(editFrame, htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Added this fix because were unable to set the Title otherwise..
/// </summary>
public class CustomGlassEditFrame : GlassEditFrame
{
    public CustomGlassEditFrame(string buttons, TextWriter writer, string dataSource = "") : base(buttons, writer, dataSource)
    {
    }

    public CustomGlassEditFrame(EditFrame frame) : base(frame)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Using HtmlHelperExtensions.BeginEditFrame(EditFrame) you will miss the writer in the RenderLastPart, this extra constructor passes the writer
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="frame"></param>
    /// <param name="writer"></param>
    public CustomGlassEditFrame(EditFrame frame, TextWriter writer)
        : base(frame.Buttons, writer, frame.DataSource)
    {

    }
}
```